# Use Flash as a link image?

Tags: flash

I guess its probably a simple thing to do - but is there anyway to use flash simply as a link image?

```
        <a href"#">link text <FLASH FILE></a>
```

I have a link animation I would like to use after each url link,  I have setup the code as
but when clicking the flash file nothing happens, only when clicking the link text.  I guess I need to turn off the interaction via a param, but cant find which to use.

Any advice gratefully received!

Cheers
Paul

Comment: are you able to modify the Flash source code? If so, then you can use getURL within Flash to add link behavior directly to your Flash animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create the link inside the flash itself, recompile and then include it into your HTML markup. It won't need to be inside an .

For the flash thing, create a layer with full width and height and assign it a click listener:

AS3:

```
myLayer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openLink);

function openLink(e:MouseEvent) {
   navigateToURL(new URLRequest("yourURLhere"));
}
```

AS2:

```
myLayer.onRelease = function() {
   getURL("yourURLhere");
}
```

You still have another tricky solution, which would be setting the `wmode` of the flash to `opaque` or `transparent` and place an  with the same dimensions over it with `z-index`.

Comment: cheers for that - it works, but too much of a pain for me as I've lots of links - so I will use the jquery method instead (http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/).  Thanks anyway though